# time.sleep() method has to be reloaded in notebook and dask distributed

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am doing a basic dask distributed tutorial and have noticed a weird behavior.

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(cluster)  # Connect to cluster
```

Then in my notebook, the following functions are defined

```
import time
def square(x):
    time.sleep(2)
    return x ** 2

def neg(x):
    time.sleep(2)
    return -x
```

The job is launched with the following cell

```
A = client.map(square, range(10))
B = client.map(neg, A)
total = client.submit(sum, B)
%time total.result()
```

The first time the above cell is executed, everything runs fine and the wall time is 20s.
But if I re-run the cell, the wall time is only a few ms....

To get things running fine again, I have to re-run the import time, def square(), def neg() cell...

I do not understand this behaviour.

I would understand having to close then relaunch the client, but redefining the two functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the situation is a little bit subtle.

Dask assigns *keys* to the objects it tracks, in this case, the futures `A`, `B` and `total`. They have keys which depend on the functions and arguments passed. Furthermore, a future will remain in the memory of the cluster so long as there remains at least one future pointing to it. So when you repeat

```
A = client.map(square, range(10))
```

(or, let's say, the first one, which would look like `submit(square, 0)`)
Dask will construct the key for the operation, and at submit time realise that there already is a result for this exact thing, so the work will not be repeated - it will just get the previous result.

Note that the cleanup of the variable `A`, which held the previous future, happens *after* a new version of `A` is assigned, so there is always a reference to the future live, and the cluster doesn't dismiss it from memory.

If you redefine the functions, Dask will give them new keys, and the previous result held in the cluster will not be used. Dask doesn't actually know the *contents* of a function (which haven't changed) only that the function is not the same object as before (i.e., it is at a different memory location).

Final note: execution in a notebook is sometimes harder to think about, since when you re-execute a cell, or go back to a previous cell, what you see on the screen is not exactly the order of inputs that the interpreter processed. It can be instructive to run the same thing in a code file (.py).